# Azure Application Gateway upgrade

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

We are going to upgrade multiple Azure Application Gateway from SKU v1, to SKU v2. 
From my searches in Microsofts documentation I am not able to find any such upgrade path there.

I am guessing that the way to do it is to create a new one, and then replace. But any experience, or other caveats with this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you guess is right. There are some features that just belong to the SKU V2 and you cannot enjoy the features through upgrade the SKU. For example, the zone configuration is supported only in regions where Azure Zones is available. What's more, some feathers of the SKU V2 are just a preview version and only available in some regions. For more details, see [Autoscaling public preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview#autoscaling-public-preview).